# Credentials are not being saved with Smart Lock API for passwords when Autofill is enabled

Tags: android, autofill, google-smartlockpasswords

I am currently implementing  Smart Lock for password in an android App, I am following the documentation:
 https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/store-credentials

in android Oreo and above there is this Autofill feature, and I DO see the autofill pop-Up in the field, my issue is when trying to save the credentials, I am getting the error:

`16: Credentials API's save confirmation dialog has been disabled to avoid conflicts with the Android Autofill feature. This choice may be overridden via CredentialsOptions.`

which I have read in other posts, is an expected error, and it is there to prevent as it states `conflicts with the Android Autofill feature` but I don't see any other dialog to confirm the saving credential.

I tried with emulators and real devices I get the same result. 
Then I tried to force the display the Smart Lock for Passwords save dialog following the documentation:

Enable the save confirmation dialog for all platforms via the CredentialsOptions when building the CredentialsClient.

```
CredentialsOptions options = new CredentialsOptions.Builder()
        .forceEnableSaveDialog()
        .build();
mCredentialsClient = Credentials.getClient(this, options);
```

Suppress the Autofill save dialog by marking the root view associated with the login fields as not important for Autofill:

```
<!-- Mark the root view with android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants" -->
<LinearLayout
    android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- ... -->
</LinearLayout>
```

I did it and it worked, the dialog was being shown when saving, but the autofill feature is gone (as expected), And I need the pop-ups, it is part of my requirements.

I also tried only applying the `CredentialsOptions options` mentioned above without the property in the XML, which didn't work. even wors, when undoing that, the app stopped working as expected and started throwing the error former mentioned, I uninstalled and restarted the phone, and still not showing the dialog and throwing the same error even though it has the fix to Suppress the Autofill applied.

I have check and the app is not in the `declined sites and apps` list
I checked system -> language -> more -> autofill -> google is selected

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys, I have found the answer myself, I am posting this in case someone else needs it.

In my specific scenario, the issue was caused by not changing the activity, I was having this issue in a small prof of concept single activity app, so the "autofill context" was not being finished. I found this concept here in the autofill documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#ensure

bottom line is either you finish the current activity and move to another one or you call:

```
 val autofillManager = requireContext().getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)
autofillManager.commit()
```

Comment: I do exactly the same, but no dialog appears. I am using TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText. Do you have any ideas why? Did you call commit before or after replacing the fragment?

Comment: @peshkira Did you find any solution? I'm also using this with Fragment and I cannot see "Save password to Google?" dialog when I go to LoginFragment to DashboardActivity.

Comment: I think so. I am not sure if it is perfect, but it it seemed to work on my devices. What I ended up doing is basically manually cancelling the session each time a text field was unfocused within my form and requesting a new autofill for the next focused view. Finally before navigating (fragment navigation, single activity), I call commit on the autofill manager as suggested.

But it seemed to work, only if I manually cancel and re-request. Not sure why.

Comment: Where did you put this code, Carlos?

Comment: i have answerd the similar question check this answer.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/76259168/9901309